# Angular: how to call a Typescript method in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created an Angular component which has a navbar, which is created as an unformatted list. By clicking on a list element, I want to call a method from the component.ts, which changes the showed component within this component.

I am an absolute beginner to Angular and web development, so I need help to solve that.

I tried using `button oncklick="methodcall()"` and `a href="methodcall()"` in the list element, which both worked. But using a button changes the styling of my navbar icons and a link shows the function call in the uri. I don't want any of this side effects.

html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="switch('page1')">page1</li>
    <li onclick="switch('page2')">page2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

component.ts:

```
switch(propertyName: string) {
    ...
}
```

An easy way to call the method without changing my styling or the uri would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `(click)` rather than `onclick`.

Something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li (click)="switch('page1')">page1</li>
      <li (click)="switch('page2')">page2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Depending on how you are switching pages I would also consider using [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router), it's incredibly powerful! Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parentheses around the event to bind it.

Template/HTML:

```
<li (click)="switch('page1')">page1</li>
```

Component.ts:

```
export class ClickMeComponent {

  public switch(pageId: string) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Here's the official Angular documentation about event binding:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li (click)="switch('page1')">page1</li>
      <li (click)="switch('page2')">page2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Should work, but remember that it is actually not semantically correct, also for accessibility reasons I would always use a button or anchor for clicks. The styling for your icon can be kept in its original state by CSS. I would advise to do the following

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" (click)="switch('page1')">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="label">page1</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" (click)="switch('page2')">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="label">page2</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```